# data boxes not displayed by gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

I'd like to do a bar chart using gnuplot.

I used this settings

```
set style data boxes
set style fill solid  
plot 'foo.dat' using 1:2:(1) linewidth 2
```

with the content of foo.dat being

```
8 1
10 1
11 4
12 4
```

gnuplot only displays the bars corresponding to the last two lines.

Why ?
Is there an other solution than adding "9 0" into my data file ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `y`-axis is probably autoscaled to [1:4]. Use e.g.

```
set yrange [0:*]
```

Then the axis always starts at 0 but is autoscaled at the other end.

Answer (score 1):

By default your graph will be autoscaled in y from 1 to 4. That's why you can't see the first two bars.

The solution: set your y-range properly.

```
set yrange[0:5]
```

**Edit:** @Christoph's good suggestion `set yrange[0:*]` will conveniently autoscale the upper end. However, here from `[0:4]` which will not look nice with the boxes touching the upper x-axis. 
Therefore, I recommend to add some margins `set offsets 0,0,1,0   # left,right,top,bottom`. Check `help margins`.

**Code:**

```
### plot boxes 
reset session

$Data <<EOD
8 1
10 1
11 4
12 4
EOD

set style data boxes
set style fill solid
set yrange [0:*]
set offsets 0,0,1,0   # left,right,top,bottom

plot $Data using 1:2:(1) w boxes linewidth 2
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]